# Robot Framework - RIDE

Tags: java, eclipse, frameworks, robotframework

How to create a Customized Library for Robot Framework in eclipse,
and how to import the Created Jar using RIDE.

When jar file is created and  try to import in RIDE,should the run configuration be as Jython.

Please Suggest an IDE for testing Customized Java Libraries using Robot Framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write your library and export it as a jar from Eclipse.

After that in Ride click Add import > Library and write your class name with full qualified package name as name. For example org.test.MyCustomLibrary.

After that you can use your methods as keywords. If there is a method named customMethod you can use it as Custom Method as keyword. Your jar file must be in classpath. Jbot has -P paramater to add folder and files to classpath.

Actually that post has more information about proccess: [Robot Framework Tutorial – Writing Keyword Libraries in Java](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/06/robot-framework-tutorial-writing-keyword-libraries-in-java/)